# The number of two specific elements between two columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have the following matrix:

```
x=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2)
M=matrix(x,9,2)
```

The matrix M is:

```
> M
 0    0
 0    1
 0    2
 1    0
 1    1
 1    2
 2    0
 2    1
 2    2
```

How do I find that the number of `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(0,2)`, `...` (that is the first row, the second, the third and so on) in the whole rows are equal to 1?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the row elements; e.g. row 1 (0, 0) is 0, row 2 (0, 1) is 1, etc.? If so, try `sum(rowSums(M) == 1)`

Comment: @duckmayr. I mean that the number of the vector (0,0) on the whole 9 rows of the matrix M is equal to 1. That is, how many are the vectors (0,0) in the whole 9 rows of the matrix M? The answer is 1.

Comment: I think I see... you mean every element of the row is equal to 1; i.e., for two columns every row that is (1, 1). In that case, try `sum(apply(M, 1, function(x) all(x == 1)))`

Comment: Not sure if you need `table` i.e. `table(paste(M[,1], M[,2], sep="_"))`

Comment: @duckmayr No it is not this. How many rows are equal to (0,0), (0,1), (0,2)...? This is an other way to expain it.

Comment: If I understand you now, @akrun's comment should do it

Comment: @arkun thank you! That is it! But how to keep just the numbers but not the 0_0, 0_1, ...?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis  it is not clear how you wanted the output.  If it is a data.frame, I posted a solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to get the frequency, use the `table`,

```
tbl <- table(paste(M[,1], M[,2], sep="_"))
```

This can be converted to a 3 column data.frame by splitting the `names` of 'tbl' into two columns and `cbind`ing the value of 'tbl'

```
cbind(read.table(text=names(tbl), sep="_", header = FALSE), value = as.vector(tbl))
```

Comment: That it is! Great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if every row appears a single time you can use

```
duplicated(data.frame(M))
```

If any of the resulting values is `TRUE` then you know some rows appear more than one time (and you know where they are).